# Pandas too many indexers when looping through a data frame. Is there a cleaner way to write my fix?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to loop through a data frame containing the upcoming NFL game schedule. This can be found at http://www.espn.com/nfl/schedulegrid. But, as I try to get team match ups by looping and index them I receive the error - pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Too many indexers.

I tried adding an axis tag to my indexing, but received the error TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed. The first set of code gives the too many indexers error, but the second code section works.

```py
#Does not work
for x in Games.iterrows():
    Team_1 = Games.iloc[x,0]
    Team_2 = Games.iloc[x,1]
    if Team_2[0] == '@':
        Home_Team = Team_2.split('@')[1]
        Away_Team = Team_1
    else:
        Home_Team = Team_1
        Away_Team = Team_2
    x = x+1

# Works, but not clean
x = 0
for y in Games.iterrows():
    Team_1 = Games.iloc[x,0]
    Team_2 = Games.iloc[x,1]
    if Team_2[0] == '@':
        Home_Team = Team_2.split('@')[1]
        Away_Team = Team_1
    else:
        Home_Team = Team_1
        Away_Team = Team_2
    x = x+1
```

I would expect that if one of these sets fails the other one would as well. Is there a better way to index these values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably forgot that `iterrows()` returns **pairs** (tuples),
composed as *(index, row)*.

So your first version of code fails just because in `Games.iloc[x,0]`
the `x` argument is a tuple, instead of an integer (the same in the next line).

A weird construction is also the attempt to add *1* to a **tuple**,
which is also the control variable of the loop and should not be
modified within this loop.

In the second version of code you don't use `y` variable.
Instead the current row number is in `x`, so you have to
increment it each time.

My proposition to change your code is as follows:

```
for idx, row in Games.iterrows():
    Team_1 = row.iat[0]
    Team_2 = row.iat[1]
    if Team_2[0] == '@':
        Home_Team = Team_2[1:]
        Away_Team = Team_1
    else:
        Home_Team = Team_1
        Away_Team = Team_2
```

Probably further you do something with these variables.

Note that:

- I replaced `iloc` with `iat`, as it returns always a **single** element,
  so it works a bit faster.
- If you have the current row in *row* variable, you don't need to
  locate this row again using *iloc*.
  It is enough to get individual fields from the current row, so this loop
  should work faster.
- Instead of *split* I used *Team_2[1:]*. It does just what you want, but
  again faster.